# Converting a.co links to amazon full links in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code for my website

```js
function extractASIN(link) {
  const asinMatch = link.match(/\/(?:dp|gp\/product|exec\/obidos|aw\/d)\/(B[0-9A-Z]{9}|\w{10})|a\.co\/(?:[^\/]+\/)?(\w{7})(\/|\?|#|$)/);
  console.log('Link:', link);
  console.log('Match:', asinMatch);
  if (asinMatch) {
    return asinMatch[1] || asinMatch[2];
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

function extractLinkID(link) {
  const linkIdMatch = link.match(/coliid=([\w\d]{10})/);
  return linkIdMatch ? linkIdMatch[1] : null;
}
```

when using the output from a a.co link for example, https://a.co/d/4nr6LFe I expect to get the product to pop up [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqh0j.png)

but instead i tend to always get redirected to the homepage of amazon [This is what gets shown, when i enter in the a.co link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv2GL.png) and was wondering if there was a way to convert the a.co to amazon.ca. This program is simply made to input any type of amazon link and for it to get converted into an affiliate link

Comment: `when using the output from a a.co link` ... can you please edit your question to include one or more examples of such links? Can you please also explain the big picture of what you are trying to do and why?